# Not able to use Authorize tag when calling Web API from Web App using OpenId

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, webapi

I am Authenticating from Azure AD in my Web App using OpenId and trying to Authorize in my Web API.

I can access my WebAPI (.NET Framework 6.0) from Web App (.NET 4.8) without any issues. However when it comes to try and use the Authorize tag in my WebAPI controller I keen getting internal errors.

**Web App - Startup.cs**

```cs
    private static string _clientId = Properties.Resource.ClientId;
    private static string _aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(Properties.Resource.AADInstance);
    private static string _tenantId = Properties.Resource.TenantId;
    private static string _RedirectUri = Properties.Resource.RedirectUri;
    private static string _clientSecret = Properties.Resource.ClientSecret;
    private string _authority = _aadInstance + _tenantId;
    private string _scope = Properties.Resource.Scope;
    
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //Set the authentication to cookies
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    
        //Create a new cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    
        //Set the openId connect authentication settings and call the WebPortal app in Azure
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = _clientId,
            Authority = _authority,
            RedirectUri = _RedirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = _RedirectUri,
            ClientSecret = _clientSecret,
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            SaveTokens = true,
            RedeemCode = true,
            Scope = _scope,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
    
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
    }
```

**Web Api code - Program.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>{options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";}).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddOpenIdConnect(openIdOptions =>{openIdOptions.ClientId = "7221484D-1550-4087-840D-7170BC566B93";openIdOptions.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/4c2ecc82-c268-467a-bb63-0e92247d5fab";openIdOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;openIdOptions.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;openIdOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";openIdOptions.SaveTokens = true;openIdOptions.ClientSecret = "****";});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbucklebuilder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()){app.UseSwagger();app.UseSwaggerUI();}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Web Api Controller - Where Authorize isn't working**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("GetRoleInfo")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRoleInfo()
{
    try
    {
        string userId = GetAzureUserId();

        List<Role> roles = await GetRoles();
        List<AdminRole> adminRoles = await GetAdminRoles();
        List<BusinessUser> businessUsers = await GetBusinessUsers();
        List<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers = await GetApplicationUsers();
        List<Application> applications = await GetApplications();

        var roleAdminModel = PopulateRoleInfo(userId, roles, adminRoles,   
        businessUsers,applicationUsers, applications);

        return Ok(roleAdminModel);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Error I am getting**

[image: Error Message]

Comment: I can't find you code in error message. Where is this code line 40?

Comment: The error is about getting a `500` response from whatever `url` is set to. Doesn't seem related to authorisation

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).